# jQuery animation is jumping / jerking outside of the parent element

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm using the MixItUp plugin for sorting. When I click a filter that I set up, everything works like a charm except for... the jumping animation towards the end.

To clarify, right before the animation and shuffle is finished, the animation jumps quickly and flys back down. The amount the animation jump is the same size as the filtered out element.

HTML

```
<div ID="Container">
<div class=" mix view-list" data-rating="random-variable" data-name="random-variable">
<div class="leftBox"></div>
<div class="mainBox"></div>
<div class="rightBox"></div>
</div></div>
```

CSS

```
#Container {
width: 100%;
padding: 0 15px;
}

.view-list {
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 100%;
height: 160px;
position: relative;
background: #303338;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.leftBox {
padding: 22px 0;
width: 24%;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}

.mainBox {
width: 52%;
height: 155px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
position: relative;
padding: 18px 0;
color: #999BA6;
}

.rightBox {
width: 24%;
height: 160px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
padding: 59px 0;
}
```

Really hoping someone can help with this, I've spent way too long being unsuccessful here.

**UPDATE**
Figured out the problem. Turns out I had multiple CSS animations assigned to the same element. Can't believe it. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Can post `js` , create stacksnippets , http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Figured it out while making the fiddle. :) Gave you a vote, thank you.